# Change stdClass property type

Tags: php, laravel, casting, stdclass

I'm going to assign a `User` model(object) to one of my stdClass properties,this is my stdclass fetched as a query result through DB :

```
{#803 ▼
+"user": 84
+"id_list": "7,1"
+"total": "125002.00"
+"settlement_id": null
+"bank_code": null
+"gateway_id": null
+"settlement_date": null
}
```

if i try to assign `User` model to `user` property an exception throw:

> Object of class App\User could not be converted to int

this is the way i try to assign User model to stdclass

```
// $settlements is an array containing stdClasses
// $user_list is an array containing User models

foreach($settlements as $settlement){
        foreach($user_list as $user){
            if($settlement->user == $user->id){
                $settlement->user = $user;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: convert it to first `(array)$variable` and then do some stuff

Comment: How are you assigning `user` property? Can we see the codes please?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `$settlement->user` is an object, which PHP tries to convert to integer while comparing it at the line which says:

`if($settlement->user == $user->id){`

You need to make sure it's not an object already assigned before performing the comparison, something like:

`if (!is_object($settlement->user) && $settlement->user == $user->id)`

or

`if (!$settlement->user instanceof User && $settlement->user == $user->id)`

(assuming that `$user` is instance of `User` class; change it to whatever it actually is)

Comment: thank for reply, but your assumption is not true, the error occur inside `if` clause ,when i try to assign a `User` model object to `$settlement->user ` that was already contained an integer

Answer (score 0):

Got it , removed the following line:

```
 if ($user > 0) {
                return response()->json('Success');
    }
```